# Why is an NSNumber property sometimes mangled when moved over the network as part of a Plist?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, network-programming

I have two different apps operating on two different Macs: a client and a server.  They use HTTP to communicate.  The server has an HTTP server which publishes plist files which encapsulates the data sent.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>sensorName</key>
      <string>external</string>
      <key>temperature</key>
      <real>8.8</real>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The Client uses an HTTPRequest and collects the data like so:

```
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        DDLogVerbose(@"URL Connection succeeded! Received %ld bytes of data",[testReceivedData length]);

        NSString *errorDescription = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;
        NSDictionary *incomingPlist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:testReceivedData
                                                                     mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                               format:&format
                                                                     errorDescription:&errorDescription];

        if (errorDescription)
        {
            DDLogError(@"Error converting data from web into plist: %@", errorDescription);
            return;
        }

        DDLogVerbose(@"We got a plist from the server: %@", incomingPlist);

        NSString *sensorName;
        switch ([self currentCommandType]) {
            case MFRemoteCommandTypeSensorIndex:
                [self setSensorNames:[incomingPlist objectForKey:@"sensorNames"]];
                break;

            case MFRemoteCommandTypeTemperature:
                sensorName = [incomingPlist objectForKey:@"sensorName"];
                if (!sensorName)
                {
                    DDLogError(@"Could not get sensorname from temperature plist: %@", incomingPlist);
                    break;
                }
                [self didReceiveTemperatureReading:(NSNumber *)[incomingPlist objectForKey:@"temperature"] ForSensorName:sensorName];
                break;

            default:
                DDLogError(@"We should never get here.");
                break;
        }

        [self clearCurrentRequest];
    }
```

So far so good.... and data is flowing between the two apps well and all is good in the world.

However, occasionally, and I cannot work out what the cause is, the client will interpret the temperature value incorrectly. i.e. instead of (as in the plist above) interpreting the temperature NSNumber as 8.8 it will interpret it as 8.800000000000001 or 9.2 as 9.199999999999999

Does anyone know why it would be doing this?  The odd thing is that there doesn't appear to be any pattern to when it does it...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Two words: Floating point.

Comment: I've just had a thought - I could pass the number value as a string - that should stop the floating point weirdness, but seems 'wrong' to me...

Comment: @Diggory It's certainly wrong, both conceptually and technically: it wouldn't make floating-point numbers precise.

Comment: Study up on floating point a bit and decide what works best for you.  Floating point is something that every programmer needs to understand fairly well, so it will be time well spent.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Not "wrong", maybe (or maybe not) "inappropriate".  Eg, if the number is being transmitted purely for display, the character representation is probably more appropriate, since that controls the format.  If it's being communicated for numerical "munching", however, then floating-point is appropriate (even though the actual value in the plist is a char string).

Comment: @HotLicks I call inappropriate things "wrong" - we're programmers, not politicians.

Comment: The number is rounded to 1dp before it even arrives at the Server from the sensor (I don't need any more accuracy than that - it's measuring the air temperature inside and outside my house.)  So I can live with turning it into a string.   Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @H2CO3 - I've learned over the years that there's usually more than one way to de-fur a feline.  Sometimes what seems like the "wrong" way is right, as when the data may be going directly to a display device.  And, even if the technique isn't ideal, if it gets the job done and had no significant hazards then I wouldn't strenuously object.

Comment: @HotLicks Fair points, I must admit. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> interpreting the temperature NSNumber as 8.8 it will interpret it as
>   8.800000000000001 or 9.2 as 9.199999999999999

Decimal numbers often don't have exact representations in floating point formats, so if you're reading the numbers as floats, you're very likely to see them displayed as something very close but not exactly the same as what you expect. If you need an exact representation, take a look at [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

By the way, you should know that decimal numbers aren't any more precise than binary representations except for those numbers which happen to have an exact decimal representation. For example, neither binary nor decimal representations can exactly represent 1/3.

Comment: I never turn the NSNumber into a float - but perhaps NSNumber does as ingests the plist.